# Upgrading my self hosted WCF service from 3.5 to 4.0 Slowed down the stratup of the service on system boot

Tags: wcf, security, startup, performance

In My winform application I have implemented self hosted WCF service accessible only on LAN.

Previously my app was in framework 3.5, now 
I have migrated to 4.0.

My application is ment to start on windows startup, and previously it was working fine.

After the migration from 3.5 to 4.0. It has started taking around 1.5 minutes to strart.

Do any of you have any Idea about this annoying delay.

Regards,
Nitin

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a bunch of issues with load times of WCF services over the years. My advice to you is to run the 3.5 version on a local workstation you can monitor with Windows Process Monitor and then do the same for the 4.0 version and compare the difference. I've seen differences from debug settings (which result in dynamic proxy creation and compilation) to .NET framework conflicts. Please post what you find with Process Monitor so that the community can benefit from your experience.